# How to remove the whitespace between '<td>' border tags

Tags: html, asp.net, css, user-interface

The first table is what I am trying to recreate and the second table is what I get.

I tried to create a table and populate the `<td>` tags with labels. After making the borders dark there are these whitespace between cells that I do not need. Is there any other method that I should try?

any suggestions on how to get results close to the second table? It is not hard-coded with values but rather filled in with asp labels.

[image: intended result]

Comment: add cellspacing="0" to your table tag

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use [`border-collapse`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/border-collapse):

```
table {
    border-collapse: collapse;
}
```

See the [examples provided here](https://developer.mozilla.org/samples/cssref/border-collapse.html).